# SQL (Redshift) concat multiple rows under one ID

Tags: sql, string, select, group-by, amazon-redshift

I have 3 columns in my table

```
Products (product_id, product_detail_name, product_detail_value)
```

For each product, I want all its details to be in a single cell, i.e in the below format:

```
product_id, concatenated_values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string aggregation function `listagg()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_LISTAGG.html):

```
select product_id, listagg(product_detail_value) product_details
from mytable
group by product_id
```

Or if you want to see the results as comma-separated `'name: value'` pairs, then:

```
select 
    product_id, 
    listagg(product_detail_name || ': ' || product_detail_value) product_details
from mytable
group by product_id
```

`listagg()` also supports an `order by` clause (with the `within group` syntax), that is described in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is very efficient and optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the second section of `LISTAGG` to define the delimiter.

```
Select product_id,
Listagg(product_detail_name || ':' || product_detail_value, ' ,') p_details
from mytable
Group By product_id;
```